# Shopping cart more details

Tags: php, sql

I'm doing a shopping cart and I want to get in new windows "More about item".

It's `get cart.php?more=id`, but nothing shows up in the page.

**cart.php** - part of code:

```
    $page2 = 'more.php';
    if(isset($_GET['more'])){
        $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['more']]; 
    }
    function more(){
        $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string($id));
        while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
        echo '<p>'.'<b>Name: </b>'.$get_row['name'].'<br/>'.'<b>About: </b>'.$get_row['description'].'<br/>'.'<b>Quantity: </b>'.$get_row['quantity'].'<br/>'.'<b>Price: </b>'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' $</p>';
        }
        header('Location: '.$page2);
    }
    function products(){
     $get=mysql_query('SELECT id, name, description,quantity,price FROM products WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY id DESC');
     if (mysql_num_rows($get)==0){
        echo "There are no products to display!";
     }
     else{
        while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
            echo '<p>'.'<b>Name: </b>'.$get_row['name'].'<br/>'.'<b>About: </b>'.$get_row['description'].'<br/>'.'<b>Quantity: </b>'.$get_row['quantity'].'<br/>'.'<b>Price: </b>'.number_format($get_row['price'], 2).' $'.'<a href="cart.php?add='.$get_row['id'].'"> Add</a>'.'<a href="cart.php?more='.$get_row['id'].'"> More</a></p>';
        }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should change

```
<a href="cart.php?more='.$get_row['id'].'"> More</a>
```

into

```
<a href="cart.php?more='.$get_row['id'].'" target="_blank"> More</a>
```

Success!